# Stop Zend_Db from quoting Sybase BIT datatype field values

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, zend-db, freetds, sap-ase

I'm using Pdo_Mssql adapter against a Sybase database and working around issues encountered. One pesky issue remaining is Zend_Db's instance on quoting BIT field values. When running the following for an insert:

$row = $this->createRow();
...
$row->MyBitField = $data['MyBitField'];
...
$row->save();

FreeTDS log output shows:

dbutil.c:87:msgno 257: "Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'BIT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I've tried casting values as int and bool, but this seems to be a table metadata problem, not a data type problem with input.

Fortunately, Zend_Db_Expr works nicely. The following works, but I'd like to be database server agnostic.

$row->MyBitField = new Zend_Db_Expr("CONVERT(BIT, {$data['MyBitField']})");

I've verified that the describeTable() is returning BIT for the field. Any ideas on how to get ZF to stop quoting MS SQL/Sybase BIT fields?

Comment: It appears that Pdo_Mssql is quoting all numeric data types :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try this (works for mysql bit type):

```
$row->MyBitField = new Zend_Db_Expr($data['MyBitField']);
```